# Display a string in a knockout bound virtual element?

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

Existing HTML looks like such:

```
<span>
  <i class='icon-class'></i> OBJECT NAME HERE
</span>
```

I realize I can add a span and bind the text value to the object name, but it breaks the existing CSS layout.  I *could* tweak the CSS, but before I go doing that (it's quite a complex template) I wanted to make sure there is not a way to do a virtual element that simply displays a string value.

```
<!-- ko string: objects.name --><!-- /ko -->
```

or something would be awesome, but from what I can see in the docs you can only use foreach or if in a virtual element.

Am I missing something or am I going to have to use a span?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text` binding:

```
<!-- ko text: objects.name --><!-- /ko -->
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RLfR/

Comment: Wow, I swear I had tried that.  Works just find now, thanks!  Wonder why the documentation implies that only "control flow bindings" can be used in virtual elements... http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html